# RadioGroup Selection check and Action according to Selection

Tags: android

I am having 2 RadioGroups in my layout.

I want user to check RadioButtons from both groups.

But I want user to select RadioButton from first group first and then from second group. So that if the user directly tries to select the RadioButton from second group it generates an error ( could be Toast or anything ) that First select the RadioButton from first group.

So I want to implement this thing so that user wont be able to select Radio Button from second group first.

e.g

Type:

o Easy o Difficult

Action:

o Add    o Subtract

These are the radio buttons from different radio groups.

If the user directly tries to select radio button from the Action group then it wont gets selected and display and error message that First Select the type.

Hope I explained my problem clearly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put this into your `onCreate`, adjusting for your IDs:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RadioGroup groupOne = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group_one);

    groupOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int index) {
            RadioGroup groupTwo = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group_two);
            for(int i = 0; i < groupTwo.getChildCount(); i++) {
                groupTwo.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And then your XML layout file should look something like this:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radio_group_one">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Group 1 button 1"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Group 1 button 2"/>
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radio_group_two">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Group 2 button 1"
        android:enabled="false"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Group 2 button 2"
        android:enabled="false"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

So the buttons in the second `RadioGroup` are disabled at first, and only becomes enabled after the user makes a selection in the first one.

Comment: Thats cool but I want to display both the RadioGroup 's because already there are only 3 views on my screen so dont wanna hide even 1 of them...Please check my edit.
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, this will do that - setting `enabled="false"` doesn't _hide_ the view, only makes it _disabled_, so that it can't be clicked.

Comment: Ok isnt there any way to display a toast and say user to select any value from first radio group?

Comment: You could add an `onCheckedChangedListener` to the second radio group that calls `getCheckedRadioButton` on the first group, and if that's -1 then you could show your toast and call `clearCheck` on the second group to remove the selection. However, you shouldn't do this - this provides a poor user experience. Simply disabling the second group until the first one is selected (as above) provides a better user experience, the expected behaviour is obvious without a prompt.

Comment: Ok I will try this and will let you know. Thanks